# MarkLogic harmonize data cleaning how to parse data and separate into

Tags: json, parsing, marklogic, data-cleaning

I am working with MarkLogic 10. I have a database that is loaded with JSON data.
I have one field that was not parsed. What I would like to do is something like:
Sample Data:

```
{"books": {"Harry Potter": {"text": "There are several harry potter books:/n-Chamber of Secrets/n--chess/n--dog/n-Goblet of Fire/n--dragon/n--broomstick "}
```

The desired output is something like:

```
{"books": {"Harry Potter": {"subject": "There are several harry potter books:",
   "book 1" : { 
    "title": "-Chamber of Secrets",
    "Contents 1" : "--chess",
    "Contents 2" : "--dog"},
       "book 2" : { 
         "title":"-Goblet of Fire",
        "Contents 1" : "--dragon",
        "Contents 2" : "--broomstick"}}}}
```

Does MarkLogic have a function that can easily do this?

Comment: It isn't clear how you expect to get from the sample input to the sample output. Can you describe the logic and what denotes different books? Why wouldn't it be an array of book objects instead of a nested structure?

Comment: Ok, not specifically using the example above, There is a master item here say "List of Tasks Done" What was done root node, secondary node first task in that first task sub-task cycle through out all task and sub-task using MarkLogic. The above would state Things Done Today top then the Task one if there are sub-task they would be nodes in that node .etc

Answer (score 1):

The mapping of lines in the text string to properties of the output object will require scripting.

Functions available in Server-Side JavaScript can do this mapping:

- Split the value of the text property into an array of strings on the newline character with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split
- Reduce the array using the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

The seed value for the reducer might be a JavaScript object that contains both the state (the depth of the prior node in the tree) and the current output object (initialized as appropriate).

The reducer function might do the following:

- Match the leading hyphens for the current string with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match
- Get the length of the leading hyphen string to determine the current depth https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length
- Update the state and the output object based on the depth:

  - Open a new object if the current depth is larger than the prior depth.
  - Close the prior object if the current depth is smaller than the prior depth.
  - Add a property at the same depth if the prior depth is the same.

The mapping could also be done in client languages with JSON support before loading.

Hoping that helps,

Comment: I there a way to use this in MarkLogic Qconsole

Comment: Yes, JavaScript along the lines sketched above should work in a QueryConsole SJS (Server-Side JavaScript) buffer or in a MarkLogic SJS module.